# Crop letter out of picture with OpenCv

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, handwriting-recognition

I'm currently writing an OCR in C++. I'm using a neural network and it works pretty well with simple letters like [this](http://i1110.photobucket.com/albums/h453/davekor/mnist_zps447d8598.png).

But now I would like to go further and extract letters out of an image, like [this one](http://www.justsomebroad.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/handwriting.jpg).

I'm using OpenCV 3 and I have no clue of how I could do this, I searched a lot on internet but I didn't find anything that could help me.

Right know I'm able to crop out most of the words by using findContours, but it seems impossible to get each letter separately.

Any help/idea would be really appreciated !

Comment: Basically everything works ok on _simple letters like that_. **Handwriting recognition** is a tough one.

Comment: Yes but my problem is not the recognition part, it's more how to get the letters out of the image to send them to my neural network

Comment: **Character extraction** is a step of "handwriting recognition". But besides terminology, I can only advice you to look for some good research papers. And this is probably _too broad_ for SO. Good luck!

Comment: You can have a look at [this paper](http://kaitman.free.fr/article/00506792.pdf) to get an idea

Comment: Nice, really interesting. I found [this one](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.academypublish.org%2Fpapers%2Fpdf%2F2584.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHICT76bBqKWC7Dweo5QQZUyqhzQg). It explain it very well and is simple enough even if you suck at math (like me :B). I should be able to do it now, thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Seems a lot of fine tuning of hardcoded thresholds, but could be a good way to become confident with the concepts... good luck!

Comment: Yes it's not perfect but as you said I think it's a good way to get familiarized with the concept ! Thanks, I'm already having some result !